# call api on click with Nuxt

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

How do I call an api with event handlers like when clicking on a button with Nuxt? I understand the `fetch()` and `asyncData()` hooks but they are called on server side rendering. But what if I want to call an API when I click on a button like:

```
//template
<button @click="myMethod"> click me </button>

// script
methods:{
  myMethod(){ 
    // call my api here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example using the [nuxt axios module](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/):

```html
<button @click="myMethod"> click me </button>
```

```js
methods:{
  myMethod() { 
    this.$axios.get('some-api-url').then(response => {
      console.log(response)
    })
  }
}
```